# Using Gradle to Rsync instead of copy

Tags: gradle, rsync

I have a project that involves moving files from one directory to another repeatedly during build and debugging processes. To help with that, I ended up making a task to file copy parts of the project from one location to another.

Is there a way to get gradle to perform an rsync instead of a copy? I feel like 2 minutes to copy all of the necessary files when only making a few changes to one isn't exactly efficient.

Or is there something wrong with gradle for it to be taking that long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't ship with rsync-like functionality, but you could call `rsync` using an `Exec` task. It's also worthwhile to check whether there is a third-party plugin.

Comment: As far as I know there's no such plugin. I used `rsync` command directly.